# Report Detail JUnit Task isn't right

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit, sikuli

I'm working with Eclipse, JUnit, Sikuli, Ant and Ubuntu.

I created a JUnit task for running a suite test and generated the report in html. In the console one of the five test cases shows this error:

> [junit] [error] Region.waitVanish: seems that imagefile could not be found on disk

On purposed, I changed the image file name for doing wrong, and the tests show no failures.

> [junit] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 780,548 sec

The problem is that generated report isn't show me the right result, because at log in console, first, junit shows me an error and second, the final result shows me that everything passed right. Is that more clear now or that line I showed is not considered an error??
Anyone could help me with this? Any ideas? Thanks so much.

Build.xml code:

```
<target name="init">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../Eclipse/eclipse"/>
    <property name="sourceDir" value="src"/>
    <property name="reportsDir" value="reports"/>
    <property name="buildDir" value="bin"/>

    <property name="target" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.5"/>

    <path id="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins/org.apache.ant.source_1.8.4.v201303080030.jar"/>
    </path>

    <path id="Tests.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${buildDir}"/>
        <pathelement location="../../Sikuli/sikuli-java.jar"/>
        <path refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath"/>
    </path>
</target>


<!-- Deletes the existing build and dist directory-->
<target name="clean" depends="init">
    <delete dir="${buildDir}" includes="**/*.class" />
    <delete dir="${reportsDir}" />
    <delete file="ReportsConsole.doc"/>
</target>

<!-- Creates the  build and dist directory-->
<target name="prepare" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${reportsDir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${reportsDir}/html"/>
    <mkdir dir="${buildDir}"/>
    <touch file="ReportsConsole.doc"/>
</target>    

<target name="compile" depends="clean,prepare">
    <javac srcdir="${sourceDir}" destdir="${buildDir}" includeantruntime="false" debug="true" optimize="true" deprecation="false" failonerror="true" compiler="javac1.7">
        <classpath refid="Tests.classpath"/>
    </javac>

    <javac srcdir="${sourceDir}" destdir="${buildDir}" includeantruntime="false" debug="true" optimize="true" deprecation="false" failonerror="true" compiler="javac1.7">
        <classpath refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath" />
    </javac>

</target>

<target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>

<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="compile"/>

<target name="test" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="true" haltonfailure="yes" showoutput="yes" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="Tests.classpath"/>
            <classpath refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath"/>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${buildDir}"/>
            </classpath>

            <formatter type="xml" usefile="true"/>
                 <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reportsDir}">
                        <fileset dir="${buildDir}">
                            <include name="**/*TestSuite01*"/> 
                        </fileset> 
                 </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>

<target name="junitreport">
    <junitreport todir="${reportsDir}">
        <fileset dir="${reportsDir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="noframes" todir="${reportsDir}/html" styledir="../../apache-ant-1.9.4/etc/"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

And the TestCase method with error:

```
@Test
public void testCTA03() throws IOException, JAXBException, FindFailed, InterruptedException {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    String filePath = "/XXXX/XXXX/workspace_Eclipse/Tests/databases/BD_CTA03.xml";

    if (filePath.equalsIgnoreCase(null)|| filePath.isEmpty()){
        throw new IOException("Arquivo BD_CTA03.xml não encontrado");
    }

    ReadDataBase rdb = new ReadDataBase();
    rdb.readdatabaseXML(filePath);
    Screen s = new Screen();
    CarregarImagens ci = new CarregarImagens();

    System.out.println("Iniciando a execução do caso de teste CTA03 - INTEGRADA 'Rodando em máquina local sem integrações' - "
            + dateFormat.format(date) + "\n");

    IniciarApp app = new IniciarApp();
    EscolherPaginaPrimaria epp = new EscolherPaginaPrimaria();
    FecharApp fapp = new FecharApp();   

    int i = 1;
    app.verificarTerminal();
    for (Item item : rdb.getTestsdata().getItem()) {
        System.out.println("\n" + i + " - Iteração de Dados\n");
        String paginaprimaria = item.getPaginaPrimaria();
        if (paginaprimaria.equalsIgnoreCase("ISOLADA")){
            System.out.println("A página primária do XML foi 'ISOLADA'\n");
        } else {
            epp.escolherPaginaPrimaria(paginaprimaria);
            s.waitVanish(ci.carregarImagens("msg_naopossuiduasredes-")); ** Inexistent Image Name for test**
            System.out.println("Mensagem informando que não possui duas redes foi exibida com sucesso!\n");


          }
        System.out.println("\n" + i + " - Iteração de Dados Concluída\n");
        i++;            
    }
    fapp.fecharApp();


    System.out.println("CTA03 - Passed\n");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: You'll have to clarify this question by adding more information. Code that reproduces the problem is best.

Comment: Hi Cory, I published the codes build.xml and the method test case with problem. Any doubts, please contact me. Thanks very much.

Comment: Okay I think the question is getting close to readable. I went through and cleaned up the question a bit, hopefully to make things more clear. So what is the exact problem? Your unit tests are all successful, so what is wrong? Edit the question to add more detail about exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Cory, I changed the question. Please, is that more clear now? I'm sorry, but my english isn't good. :-( Thanks